# Detecting End of ScrollView Animation Without Blocks

Tags: ios, animation, uigesturerecognizer

I have a scrollview that automatically scrolls down a webview when loaded but unfortunately I am unable to put the animations inside of a scroll view due to the need to pause the animation if the user touches the screen.

I am having problems detecting the end of the animation without using the blocks.Here is my code and you can see all of the delegate methods that I have tried to hit:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    repeatCount = 0;

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    self.scrollView.delegate=self;


    NSString *htmlMessage =@"";

    //Get text from local file and sent it to webview
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"creditsMessage" ofType:@"txt"];

    if (filePath) {
        NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        if (myText) {
            htmlMessage = [htmlMessage stringByAppendingString:myText];
        }
    } else {
        htmlMessage = _defaultErrorDocumentFileMissing;
    }

    //Load the HTML Message:
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlMessage baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
    [self.webView sizeToFit];

}

 -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:YES];

    setTimer = FALSE;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pauseLayer:)];
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    [recognizer release];


    //Start the scrolling
    [self animateScroll];
}


- (void) animateScroll{
    CGFloat scrollHeight = 710;
    [UIScrollView beginAnimations:@"scrollAnimation" context:nil];
    [UIScrollView setAnimationDuration:18.0f];
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,scrollHeight)];
    [UIScrollView commitAnimations];
    [UIScrollView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIScrollView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
}


- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString*)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void *)context {
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:NO];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1500)];
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
}



    - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if (self.scrollView.layer.timeOffset>0) {
        [self resumeLayer:self.scrollView.layer]; //resume the animation on the subsequent touch
    }
    else {
        //first we pause the animation
        [self pauseLayer:self.scrollView.layer];

        //after certain seconds we will start again the animation
        double delayInSeconds = 2.0; //adjust this value
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [self resumeLayer:self.scrollView.layer];
        });
    }
    return YES;
}

-(void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer {
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
    layer.speed = 0.0;
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
}


-(void)resumeLayer:(CALayer*)layer{
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
    layer.speed = 1.0;
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
    layer.beginTime = 0.0;
    CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
}



//Works on start of scroll
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

}


//None of the below work
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{

}




-(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

}
```

Comment: Set a `flag=true` when animation starts, whenever the scroll view `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` method is called, check if that `flag==true`, which will tell you that animation was `ON` but has now stopped/paused. Then set this `flag=false` for further flow.

Comment: The scrollViewDidEndDecelerating method is never called. The only delegate method that is called is scrollViewDidScroll which is called at the beginning of the animation.

Comment: @user1079052 you must select the accepted answer in your previous questions,so others users know what helped you and also to give the people that helped you the reputation that they deserve.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
– scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:
```